Proving equality of linear interpolation and weighted approach
EDIT
To give some context to improve this question's generalization:
Take 2 points $v_1$ and $v_2$ which should be averaged with weights depending on their distance to the wanted point in-between $v_i$. One linear approach could be:
$$v_i = v_1 + t_1 * \frac{\Delta v}{\Delta t} = v_1 + t_1 * \frac{v_2 - v_1}{t_1 + t_2} $$
where
$$t_1 \text{ is the distance between } v_1 \text{ and } v_i$$
$$t_2 \text{ is the distance between } v_2 \text{ and } v_i.$$
$$
v_1 + t_1 * \frac{v_2 - v_1}{t_1 + t_2} = 
\frac{v_{1}t_{2}+v_{2}t_{1}}{t_{1}+t_{2}}
$$
A different method assumed to arrive at the same conclusion could be:
$$
v_i = \frac{\frac{v_{1}}{t_{1}}+\frac{v_{2}}{t_{2}}}{\frac{1}{t_{1}}+\frac{1}{t_{2}}} 
$$
In words: Multiplying each point with the reciprocal of its distance to the interpolation point and dividing all by the sum of "weights" (the sum of reciprocals).
Original question:
I have tried proving a certain equality, and managed to simplify it until this point:
$$
\frac{v_{1}t_{2}+v_{2}t_{1}}{t_{1}+t_{2}} = \frac{\frac{v_{1}}{t_{1}}+\frac{v_{2}}{t_{2}}}{\frac{1}{t_{1}}+\frac{1}{t_{2}}}
$$
However, I am struggling to find a way how to bring either side to the form of the other one. The only reason I assume that it is satisfied is because WolframAlpha's result showed it. I would appreciate any help towards the right direction!

Multiply numerator and denominator on the right by $t_1t_2$

$ \frac{v_{1}t_{2}+v_{2}t_{1}}{t_{1}+t_{2}}=\frac{t_{2}t_{1}\left( \frac{v_{1}}{t_{1}}+\frac{v_{2}}{t_{2}}\right)}{t_{1}+t_{2}}=
\frac{ \frac{v_{1}}{t_{1}}+\frac{v_{2}}{t_{2}}}{\frac{t_{1}+t_{2}}{t_{2}t_{1}}}
= \frac{\frac{v_{1}}{t_{1}}+\frac{v_{2}}{t_{2}}}{\frac{1}{t_{1}}+\frac{1}{t_{2}}}$

Multiplying the top and bottom of the RHS by $t_1t_2$ gives the result immediately after some cancellations:
$\frac{\frac{v_1}{t_1}+\frac{v_2}{t_2}}{\frac{1}{t_1}+\frac{1}{t_2}}=\frac{\frac{v_1}{t_1}t_1t_2+\frac{v_2}{t_2}t_1t_2}{\frac{1}{t_1}t_1t_2+\frac{1}{t_2}t_1t_2}=\frac{v_1t_2+v_2t_1}{t_2+t_1}$
Generally, multiplying the top and bottom by the common denominator is a safe move towards simplifying.

This is the stratgy I always recommend
